# Getting the signed data after signing it

Tags: java, security, digital-signature

Well when I studied signature files in Java, I aways read that you hash your file and attach the hash to the actual file, do the encryption, and send it to (for example) the server. In the server you decrypt the file, get the file, create a hash of it and if it's new hash is equals the client's hash, the file is really the client one's.

BUT now that I have to implement it in my project, I can only find examples using java.security.Signature [(like this one)](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/SignatureSignAndVerify.htm), and in these examples, they sign the file, and then send the file and the signed file to the verification instead of only sending the signed file.

Is this the correct way of implementing it? If not, what is the best way? Please give some directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no connection between encrypting the file and signing it. You can do either or both independently.

To sign, you calculate the hash, encrypt the hash using the private key, and send the encrypted hash along with the document (file).
To verify, you calculate the hash of the document you received, decrypt the encrypted hash using the public key, and compare the two. If the hashes match, the signature is verified.

Since verification uses the public key, anyone can verify a signature. But only the person (or entity) with the private key can sign it. And so it proves the origin of the document.

In addition to that, if you so wish, you can encrypt the file. You can sign the file before or after the encryption. It all depends on what you want to do with it and how secure you want to keep it. For example, SSL certificates are not encrypted, because the browser has to check their content as well as their signatures.

Comment: Thanks a lot @omrib and @user384706 , but what I want to know if there is a way of sending the document and the signature together instead of separately like in theses charts that I found here http://www.lintech.org/embedded/JaimeWong/signature.gif and here http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2b/Digital_Signature_diagram.svg/350px-Digital_Signature_diagram.svg.png

Comment: That's really up to you. You can simply append the signature to the file, or use some more complex structure to add it to the file. For example, X.509 certificates are sent with the signature (and the signature algorithm) embedded in the certificate, not as two separate files. But that's really down to you - there is no standard on how to send signatures (except as part of a larger standard, such as X.509).

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, but... How can I append in Java? that's what I want to know

Comment: Sorry, that would be a Java question... If it's a fixed sized signature (e.g. 2048 bits = 256 bytes), you can just decide that the last 256 bytes of the document is the signature. Otherwise you may want to restructure the document - for example add a header that contains the type/size of the signature, and its offset (just an example). But all of this belongs to Java, so I suggest you ask again and get a better answer than I can provide.

Answer (score 3):

The link you posted just shows an example, where the second half of the code calling
`public static boolean verifySig(byte[] data, PublicKey key, byte[] sig)`  is just validating the first half of the code that created the signature.
The idea is that in the `signer.initVerify(key);` you pass the public key of the signer, then call `signer.update(data);` on the data you **think** the signature is based on, and then call verify passing it the signature.
If the signature you passed in, is valid for the data that you think the signature is based on, then the verification is succesfull.